# Is There a Library With All Versions of Google Canary? Or a Quick Way To Add All Audio and Video Codecs To Chromium?

Tags: audio, html5-video, chromium, codec, chrome-canary

I am using an old version of Google Canary. However, for the past two days, the browser has been flickering dark at random intervals... It looks like an eye blink... This causes the browser to shut down after some time.

> **The main reason I use the old version is:** I cannot access some websites without a VPN. But in the old version I use, I can access every website without a VPN.
>
> "I don't know why; but that's how it is."

But the problem I have had for the past two days has made the browser unusable.

So I downloaded some [Chromium Builds](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/).

Similarly, in some of these builds, I can access websites that require a VPN (for example: expressvpn.com | 4shared.com) without a VPN.

But I can't play some video content. For instance, the videos on the "https://vimeo.com/" website don't open.

When I did some research, I learned that Chromium doesn't support some audio/video codecs.

Unfortunately, Google Canary doesn't have a library where we can download older versions.
Or if it does, I am not aware of it. (A reliable library from Google; like Chromium.)
Because of this, I can't download and try any newer versions of Google Canary after the one I am currently using.

And at this point, I wonder how I can add all the audio codecs to Chromium, which has all versions available for download.

I did some research and saw that they all involve coding operations.

I just believe it shouldn't be this hard.
I am a regular user; so I need the simplest way.
All the instructions in the research process are too superficial for normal users who don't know how to code and who are not developing for Chromium.

In other words, the instructions are not step-by-step for normal users; they are presented as leaps and we don't know what to do between leaps.

[Some websites](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) have added codecs for certain versions; but unfortunately the Git accounts of the people who added them don't have enough history... For this and some other additional reasons, they are not trustworthy.

For example, I saw that it compiled a version with codecs for version "`114.0.5735.91 (1135570)`".

However, I could not decide whether it is reliable or not; which even if I decide I don't know if this version contains what I need.
That's why I'm wondering; Can I use the source files at "[GITHUB](https://github.com/Hibbiki/chromium-win64/releases/tag/v114.0.5735.91-r1135570)" in all versions of Chromium?

If the answer is yes; what steps should i follow? Or is there a simple new method other than that?

Or do you have a recommendation for a guide that explains everything from A to Z as if we were normal users? Or does Google have a library where we can download older versions of Canary?

Finally; why do some versions allow us to open websites that need a VPN without a VPN?

PS: I want you to know with all my heart that I appreciate any information in advance.
And... If this question is not suitable for the main theme of the platform, please indicate.

Answer (score 0):

cannot believe no one has answered this.  still having a problem? AFAIK (As Far As I Know) Canary is a often-updated version of chrome that is *inherently unstable*. it is useful for running Chrome 'headless,' that is, without the Graphical User Interface (GUI) -- which in turn is absolutely essential if, say, you need to do something tedious on a webpage & then take a screenshot -- thousands of times over -- for a project. (side note:  i just recently developed a rudimentary but hands-on understanding of this, in order to create animated videos historical ocean temperature data: the [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NskAtk3tQk) from screenshots of every day 2015-present, & then, to check that, i made the [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcY6bZxnq5A), from government-software-generated-graphs of every day, 1981-present.  in the first instance, i took screenshots via headless chrome -- or rather, i set up a script, & it took them for me;  in the second, i got it to navigate to, set up, & download jpegs of the graphs.)

i tell you this to illustrate why someone would be using Canary.  why are *you* using canary, instead of a regular build of Chrome? is it the VPN thing?  you could more easily find an older version of chrome, set it up how you like it, & back that up, so whenever Chrome updates -- & by hook, by crook, or by stopping the clock on your machine, it most likely eventually will -- you can just revert back to the version that works best for you.  (it may be that there are other little tricks, if you ask around.  i may know more as well).

if its just a vimeo thing, perhaps something like [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) (a.k.a. [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)) would be just the thing for you.  it boasts how it can download videos from  thousands sites like YouTube, Vimeo, Facebook, Instagram, Tik Tok & Twitter -- and it downloads them easy as pie & blisteringly fast. all you need is the same url address you use to access it, and a lack of fear when doing something that looks more advanced than it is, like cutting and pasting code into a command line terminal. (there's even an online [version](https://projectlounge.pw/ytdl)).

NOTE:  i make mention of these resources because *for years* i surfed the web via an ancient laptop, & the *only* way i could watch video was by downloading it.  i thought my experience might be of use.

Comment: Hey Female Faust, Thank you for your time. 
I came across Canary at a time when I needed more than one browser. 
There was a site where I searched for "Subtitle" files in other languages for some old movies. And for some reasons, this site was closed to traffic from my country. And it was not possible to access that site without a VPN... 
However, Canary showed that I could access that site without a VPN...

Comment: However, as you said, this was not a stable version and was constantly receiving updates.  I had stopped the updates; However, later on, errors that were not present at the beginning began to occur and it became unusable. 

At this point, I met Chromium; but this did not support many video formats. Another reason is Chromium; It was much simpler than Canary and Google Chrome and worked without tiring the computer. 
The only thing missing (for me) was the HTML5-video license. And I wanted to solve this somehow. 
But it remained unresolved...

Comment: Apart from all this; I was also using Chrome; but it wasn't like Chrome Canary. 
I compared the same versions of both; However, as I mentioned, Canary did not need VPN; but Chrome did not allow access to those sites without VPN. So I continued to use Canary primarily. 

And, yes, I agree. Canary (and Chromium) is a very nice option to run in the background and retrieve data.